# USB Harddrive not working after being bumped during download

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, usb, fdisk

I recently bumped my external hard-drive whilst downloading to it, and now my computer seems unable to recognize it.
Any help available to help me retrieve the data would be appreciated/worshiped.

It is a 1TB NTFS external drive. I typically use Windows, but I dual boot into Ubuntu 18.04

I don't really known anything about what I'm doing, but I have included the information that other forums seemed to request when discussing similar issues.

It can be seen by 'lsusb' but not on "fdisk -l."

Output from 'lsusb':

> Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bc2:ab24 Seagate RSS LLC
>   Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
>   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:070f Microsoft Corp. LifeChat LX-3000 Headset
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

The device is a Seagate hard-drive, so I presume it's Bus 002. The other devices present lead me to believe that there is not a USB issue.

After running "dmesg | tail -n 20" after re-plugging in my device, I get the following:

> [ 4622.912025] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc, logical block 4, async page read
>   [ 4622.912077] Dev sdc: unable to read RDB block 0
>   [ 4622.912280]  sdc: unable to read partition table
>   [ 4623.247493] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: >hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
>   [ 4623.247499] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
>   [ 4623.519433] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
>   [ 4623.519439] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense not available.
>   [ 4623.623540] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
>   [ 4623.623546] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 2048-byte physical blocks
>   [ 4623.839571] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
>   [ 4626.431790] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
>   [ 4626.456636] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=ab24
>   [ 4626.456642] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
>   [ 4626.456646] usb 2-2: Product: BUP Slim BK
>   [ 4626.456650] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
>   [ 4626.456653] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: NA7S7B1M
>   [ 4626.459314] scsi host6: uas
>   [ 4626.463072] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  BUP Slim BK      0304 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
>   [ 4626.463964] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
>   [ 4626.463997] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...

The summary for I receive when I run "fdisk -l" is:

> Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors    Size  Id  Type
>   /dev/sda1,   *          2048, 233507907, 233505860, 111.4G,  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>   /dev/sda2,         233508864, 234436607,    927744,   453M, 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>   Disklabel type: dos
>   Disk identifier: 0x17556621
>
> Device      Boot       Start         End     Sectors    Size Id  Type
>   /dev/sdb1  *           2048,     206847,     204800,   100M,  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>   /dev/sdb2            206848, 1898525408, 1898318561, 905.2G,  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
>   /dev/sdb3        1898526718, 1953523711,   54996994,  26.2G,  5 Extended
>   /dev/sdb5        1898526720, 1953523711,   54996992,  26.2G, 83 Linux
>
> Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.

When I try to run Gparted without the removable hard drive plugged in, it runs fine, and doesn't see the external drive when I plug it in and run "refresh devices"

However if I try to run Gparted with the drive plugged it, it hangs on "scanning all devices", until I remove the device, at which point I receive the following error "Could not stat device /dev/sdc - No such file or directory." - The notification is titled "Libparted error"

I do have a SATA/IDE to USB 2.0 Hard drive adapter on hand, but I would like to delay breaking the drive case if I could.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Billy

Comment: When the device is plugged in does the disk actually spin up? Put your ear close to the disk and listen carefully. if the disk makes a buzzing noise and you don't hear it whirring up to speed then the read/write heads are stuck on the platters. if the disk spins up and you hear the disk heads moving, do they sound like they move to a single position and then "click" back. This would indicate a head or platter issue such as a scratch (from the knock) whilst the disk heads were on the platter. The distance between head and platter are measured in microns (for some perspective).

Comment: What's wrong with "breaking the drive case", does it not unscrew easily? Is it still under warranty & you're going to exchange it? Trying a direct (sata) connection is an easy way to rule out the usb enclosure parts, especially if it has it's own fan that might mask the drive's spinning sounds (or just being in a case quiets them). So far it sounds broken, time to recover from backups

Comment: Hi guys,
Thanks for your reply.
I'm not sure to make the following results.
After plugging in the drive into the SATA/IDE adapter, I hear approx. 20 short, electrical sounding beeps, less than half a second apart.
"lsusb" sees the USB port as unoccupied.
When I reconnect without the SATA adapter, I hear the same beeps, and lsusb recognizes it as a Seagate drive.
However, "fdisk -l" still displays "Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary."